# an explanation as to the point of the onCreate method

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I am new to java and all I am looking for is a good explanation to what goes in this onCreate statement and what goes outside it and its main function.

```
public class activity_main extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [relevant JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)), `AppCompatActivity` inherits the `onCreate()`method from `FragmentActivity`, and the method serves the purpose of performing the initialization of [fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment). Therefore, that method should contain everything you need strictly to initialize the fragments. And everything not needed for that initialization should go elsewhere.

Comment: More specifically what do you mean by fragments?

Comment: I linked the Fragments JavaDoc too (or well, the JavaDoc for the support library for the deprecated fragments API). If you follow it you'll see that a fragment is "a piece of an application's user interface or behavior that can be placed in an Activity".

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious functions of `onCreate`:

- setting the activity view
- working with saved state (check if activity was restored, getting saved data, etc)
- as it is a popular entry point, you could initialize/define your helpers, providers, callbacks, etc
- defining initial state of views, behavior, etc.
- show fragments if expected

All of this should not necessarily be presented in current one method, but it could. Depends on your application design, requirements and objectives.

> what goes outside

The whole world is outside